# Looking for an alternative to $(window).load that is slower than $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to hide my preloader with JavaScript once the DOM and at least the top content has been loaded. The problem is that my page has several iframes which can slow the process down a lot.

My understanding is that if I use jQuery's $(document).ready to hide the preloader, it will be hidden too soon. On the other hand, if I use $(window).load, the waiting time may be too long. So, is there a middle-way solution, - kind of like window.load but without waiting for iframes?

EDIT:
My page has stuff like Facebook Like button Google Translate and a few other scripts that work via iframes. These are *not critical elements*, and I *would not like to wait for them* to load fully.

On the other hand, CSS files like Bootstrap, jQuery, etc. are curcially important for the presentation, and therefore to show the page (hide preloader) w/o having these loaded first would be premature.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use $(document).ready to determine if a particular element is loaded before hiding your loader.

Or if you have partial views, to have a $(document).ready function in one of those pages js do the loader hide job.

Since you did not provide more info, these are closer to guesses than real solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `document.onload`, which will fire when the DOM tree is ready.  I believe that it fires before iframes, which all get their own onload callback/event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try placing the script tag at the end of your html file without begin inside an `onload` or `ready` function. This will cause it to load the html content, then fire the Javascript.

EDIT

A thought just occurred to me, which may or may not be useful. You probably have an idea about when you want your script to execute. In whatever browser you are using, check the network tab of the development console. There may be some other element's onload function you want to wrap your code in. For example, if you have a background image you want to make sure loads before your code executes, you may want to use it's onload.

As Petre said, lack of info in the question makes answering difficult.